# How do I create an FSRef from a NSString containing a path?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, filesystems

I have a file system path in a NSString, but I need an FSRef for the system call I will be making. What is the best way to create the FSRef?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try FSPathMakeRef:

```
NSString *path = @"Some... path... here";
FSRef f;
OSStatus os_status = FSPathMakeRef((const UInt8 *)[path fileSystemRepresentation], &f, NULL);

if (os_status == noErr) {
    NSLog(@"Success");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`FSPathMakeRef()`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSPathMakeRef) to make an `FSRef` from a UTF-8 C string path, and you can use the [`-UTF8String`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/UTF8String) method of `NSString` to get a UTF-8 C string:

```
FSRef fsref;
Boolean isDirectory;
OSStatus result = FSPathMakeRef([myString UTF8String], &fsref, &isDirectory);
if(result < 0)
    // handle error
// If successful, fsref is valid, and isDirectory is true if the given path
// is a directory.  If you don't care about that, you can instead pass NULL
// for the third argument of FSPathMakeRef()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method from Nathan Day in his an NSString+NDCarbonUtilities category:

```
- (BOOL)getFSRef:(FSRef *)aFSRef
{
    return FSPathMakeRef( (const UInt8 *)[self fileSystemRepresentation], aFSRef, NULL ) == noErr;
}
```

See NDAlias at http://homepage.mac.com/nathan_day/pages/source.xml for more (MIT Licensed).